# An Application of Girsanov theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to find the Radon-Nikodym of the path measures $P_X, P_Z$ associated to the following processes
\begin{align*}
dX_t & = h(X_t)dt + dB_t,\\
dZ_t & = g(Z_t)dt + dB_t.
\end{align*}
Is the following correct (assuming everything is well defined)? Let us denote by $P_W$ the path measure of the Brownian. Girsanov's theorem says that
\begin{equation} 
\frac{d P_X}{d P_W}(B) = \exp\left( \int_0 ^T h(B_t) dB_t - \frac{1}{2} \int_0 ^T h(B_t)^2 dt \right)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation} 
\frac{dP_W}{dP_Z}(Z) = \exp\left( - \int_0 ^T g(Z_t) d Z_t + \frac{1}{2} \int_0 ^T g(Z_t)^2 dt\right)
\end{equation}
Thus,
\begin{equation}
\frac{dP_X}{dP_Z}(Z) = \exp\left( \int_{0}^T \big( h(Z_t) - g(Z_t) \big) dZ_t - \frac{1}{2} \int_{0} ^T \big(h(Z_t)^2 - g(Z_t)^2 \big) dt \right).
\end{equation}